# HtmlTextWriter to export gridview to excel is generating blank space in excel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYF1I.png%60Response.Clear();)

I am getting gridview data dispayed as shown in the image where all other cells which do not have any data are coming as completely blank white page rather than excel sheet. How will I get excel sheet for the rest of the space?

```
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PMSUptimeReport.xls");
        //string style = @"<style> td { mso-number-format:\@;} </style>";
        //Response.Write(style);
        Response.Charset = "";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#FFFFFF");
        //Applying stlye to gridview header cells
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            //Change to Blue
            gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1");
        }
        int j = 1;
        //This loop is used to apply stlye to cells based on particular row
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gv.Rows)
        {
            gvrow.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (j <= gv.Rows.Count)
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                    {
                        gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                    }
                }
            }
            j++;
        }



        gv.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();[enter image description here][2]`
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: By the way this is about the 100th time I posted that comment. Where do people find the code for exporting to excel this way?